# Google Cloud SQL migration to second generation maintaining instance name

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We are currently using first generation cloud sql for MySQL.
To migrate to second generation, as indicated in documentation, we must first export the databases and then import the data from the second generation instance.

My question is, if we export all the data, then we **delete the first generation instance** with name XXXXXXXXXXX, if I create a new second generation instance, can I use the same XXXXXXXXXX name of the old deleted instance? Do I have to wait until the name is available again?

We need this because if we change the instance name we have to fix many lines of code in a production app... obviously this time we will parametrize the instance name, but it will save a lot of development time if we can export and create a new instance with the same old name.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation: "You cannot reuse an instance name for up to a week after you have deleted an instance"

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/delete-instance